# bash wildcard with variables inside an if statement

Tags: string, bash, if-statement, wildcard

I want to find substring in a string according to [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/229551/string-contains-in-bash).

But for some reason it doesn't work with variables:

```
str="abcd";
substr="abc";
if [[ "${substr}"* == ${str} ]]
then
        echo "CONTAINS!";
fi
```

Comment: substr has to be after the `==`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In the reference manual, [section *Conditional Constructs*](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Conditional-Constructs), you will read, for the documentation of `[[ ... ]]`:

> When the `==` and `!=` operators are used, **the string to the right of the operator is considered a pattern** and matched according to the rules described below in [Pattern Matching](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pattern-Matching), as if the `extglob` shell option were enabled.

(emphasize is mine).

So you need to put your glob pattern *to the right of the `==` operator*:

```
if [[ $str == "$substr"* ]]; then
```

Note that the left-hand side needs not be quoted, but the part `$substr` of the right-hand side *needs to be quoted*, in case it contains glob characters like `*`, `?`, `[...]`, `+(...)`, etc.

Comment: This saved me! My issue was from adding quotes around the variable I'm checking $str