# Substring of string matching regex in a bash shell

Tags: regex, bash, unix, substring

In a bash shell, I want to take the take a given string that matches a regex, and then take the part of the string.

For example, given `https://github.com/PatrickConway/repo-name.git`, I want to extract the `repo-name` substring.

How would I go about doing this? Should I do this all in a shell script, or is there another way to approach this?

Comment: Do it however you want. Have you made any attempts up to now?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [String contains a substring in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/229551/608639).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a `bash`y way of doing it:

```
var="https://github.com/PatrickConway/repo-name.git"
basevar=${var##*/}
echo ${basevar%.*}
```

...which gives `repo-name`

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte very good point! - edited accordingly

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: Good reference:  https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `=~` matching operator inside a `[[ ... ]]` condition:

```
#!/bin/bash
url=https://github.com/PatrickConway/repo-name.git
if [[ $url =~ ([^/]*)\.git ]] ; then
    echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
fi
```

Each part enclosed in parentheses creates a capture group, the corresponding matching substring can be found in the same position in the BASH_REMATCH array.

- `[...]` defines a character class
- `[/]` matches a character class consisting of a single character, a slash
- `^` negates a character class, `[^/]` matches anything but a slash
- `*` means "zero or more times"
- `\.` matches a dot, as `.` without a backslash matches any character

So, it reads: remember a substring of non-slashes, followed by a dot and "git".

Or maybe a simple parameter expansion:

```
#!/bin/bash
url=https://github.com/PatrickConway/repo-name.git
url_without_extension=${url%.git}
name=${url_without_extension##*/}
echo $name
```

`%` removes from the right, `#` removes from the left, doubling the symbol makes the matching greedy, i.e. wildcards try to match as much as possible.

Comment: Thank you! Fantastic explanation - just what I was looking for. I was trying to use grep with a complex regex...this is much better!