# Bash to test regex-match, seems to always return OK even not match

Tags: string, bash, testing, expression, match

I'm under bash and tried to match a short string with a pattern:

```
$[[ "ab" =~ "^a*" ]]
$echo $?
0
```

OK, as I expected, but then I changed into "^b*", I expect this time, it doesn't match:

```
$[[ "ab" =~ "^b*" ]]
$echo $?
0
```

Strangely the return value is still "OK". Why is that, where did I get wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: `^b*` means 0 or more `b` at start so obviously it will match any input.

Comment: don't use double-quotes on RHS!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regex `^b*` means `0` or more `b` at the start so obviously it will return true for any input.

You should use `+` quantifier for 1 or more matches and avoid quoting regex in bash as this:

```
[[ "ab" =~ ^a+ ]] && echo 'ok' || echo 'no'
ok

[[ "ab" =~ ^b+ ]] && echo 'ok' || echo 'no'
no
```

Likewise you can use `^a` or `^a.*` as well.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [anubhava's correct answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44774190/1765658), and because *bash's regex* are particulary expensive, I would say:

If your need is to check for presence of a character at 1st position of a string, and because this kind of test have to be done against *variables*:

```
myVar="ab"

[ "$myVar" ] && [ -z "${myVar%%a*}" ] && echo "String '$myVar' begin with 'a'"
```

will output: `String 'ab' begin with 'a'`, but

```
myVar="ab"

[ "$myVar" ] && [ -z "${myVar%%b*}" ] && echo "String '$myVar' begin with 'b'"
```

won't produce anything!

See also: [String contains in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/229551/string-contains-in-bash/20460402#20460402)