# Finding a string in a varaible with if statement

Tags: string, bash, variables

I am currently trying to find a string within a variable that outputs something like this:

> one,two,three

My code:

```
echo "please enter one,two or three)
read var

var1=one,two,threee

if [[ "$var" == $var1 ]]; then
    echo "$var is in the list"
else
    echo "$var is not in the list"
fi
```

EDIT2:

I tried this but still not matching. Yo uwere correct about it not matching the exact string from previous answers as it was matching  partial.

```
 groups="$(aws iam list-groups --output text | awk '{print tolower($5)}' | sed '$!s/$/,/' | tr -d '\n')"
echo "please enter data"
read "var"

if [ ",${var}," = *",${groups},"* ]; then
    echo "$var is in the list"
else
    echo "$var is not in the list"
fi
```

Trying this its still not matching the exact string as i need it to.

Comment: what language is this?

Comment: bash script ...

Comment: can you add a tag 'bash', please?

Comment: how about? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/229551/string-contains-in-bash

Comment: my var1 is a command that runs and outputs data like i mentioned above. so i'm comparing $var to $var1 but it never successfully finds any strings i put from $var

Comment: @hhh0505 It looks like there's still something weird in the variables. Try adding `declare -p var groups` just before the `if`, and see what it prints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There might be other problems (like matching partial words), but if you use `=~` (match) instead of `==` it would work for simple cases

```
if [[ "$var1" =~ "$var" ]]; then
   ...
```

Comment: tried that , same thing. To give more context im using aws API to list IAM groups.

var1=aws iam list-groups --output text | awk '{print $5}' | sed '$!s/$/,/

when i echo it from my script it shows up like this:
admin, dev, stage

Comment: This worked, my mistake with a typo.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers have a problem in that they'll treat matches of *part* of an item in the list as a match, e.g. if `var1=`admin,\ndev, \nstage`(which I think is what you actually have), then it'll match if`var`is "e" or "min", or a bunch of other things. I'd recommend either removing the newlines from the variable (maybe by adding`| tr -d '\n'` to the end of the pipeline that creates it), and using:

```
if [[ ",${var}," = *",${var1},"* ]]; then
```

(The commas around `$var` anchor it to the beginning and end of an item, and the ones around `$var1` allow it to word for the first and last items.) You could also make it work with the newlines left in `$var1`, but that's the sort of thing that'll mess you up sooner or later anyway.

Comment: Check my edit , i'm still unable to match the string out of the list. But your explanation that the others will match different scenarios is correct as that's what it was doing.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "please enter one,two or three"
read var

var1=["one","two","three"]


if [[ ${var} = *${var1}* ]]; then
    echo "${var} is in the list"
else
    echo "${var} is not in the list"
fi
```