# how to get a particular line from a string array

Tags: bash, shell, unix

```
/server/fmw/idm_111/opatch2019-01-25_08-20-55AM_1.log 
/server/fmw/oamwebgate11g/opatch2019-01-25_08-20-57AM_1.log 
/server/fmw/ohs_111/opatch2019-01-25_08-20-59AM_1.log 
/server/fmw/oracle_common/opatch2019-01-25_08-21-01AM_1.log
```

above is the content of a string array in a shell, want to get the line which has ohs_111

Comment: How are you printing/storing the array? Which shell are you on?

Answer (score 2):

[grep](https://linux.die.net/man/1/grep) - print lines matching a pattern.

For example:

```
grep -F ohs_111 file_with_content
```

Also grep could be used in script:

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash

array=("/server/fmw/idm_111/opatch2019-01-25_08-20-55AM_1.log"
    "/server/fmw/oamwebgate11g/opatch2019-01-25_08-20-57AM_1.log"
    "/server/fmw/ohs_111/opatch2019-01-25_08-20-59AM_1.log"
    "/server/fmw/oracle_common/opatch2019-01-25_08-21-01AM_1.log")

for line in ${array[@]}; do
    grep ohs_111 <<< $line
done
```

Output:

```
/server/fmw/ohs_111/opatch2019-01-25_08-20-59AM_1.log
```

Comment: Why the `.*` ? You can remove them. Without `-x` option to grep it doesn't match the whole line exact, only part of it.

Answer (score 1):

see the example below:

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash
array=("hi...." "..foo/.." "..bar/..")
for i in ${array[@]}; do
    if [[ "$i" =~ "foo" ]] ; then
        echo "$i"
    fi
done
```

output:

```
..foo/..
```

Answer (score 0):

as it is explained in [How to check if a string contains a substring in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/229551/how-to-check-if-a-string-contains-a-substring-in-bash) for instance doing :

```
#!/bin/bash

array=("/server/fmw/idm_111/opatch2019-01-25_08-20-55AM_1.log" 
       "/server/fmw/oamwebgate11g/opatch2019-01-25_08-20-57AM_1.log" 
       "/server/fmw/ohs_111/opatch2019-01-25_08-20-59AM_1.log"
       "/server/fmw/oracle_common/opatch2019-01-25_08-21-01AM_1.log" )

for i in ${!array[*]}
do
  if [[ "${array[$i]}" == *"ohs_111"* ]]
  then
    echo "${array[$i]}"
  fi
done
```