# Bash compare a command output to string

Tags: bash, git-bash

Output is same, and it always echos `need to pull`.
If I remove the quotes around `$text` in `if` condition it throws the `too many arguments` error.

```
var="$(git status -uno)" && 

text="On branch master Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'. nothing to commit (use -u to show untracked files)"; 

echo  $var; 
echo  $text; 
if [ "$var" = "$text" ]; then
    echo "Up-to-date"
else
    echo "need to pull"
fi
```

Comment: The output of `git status` is not a single line of text. In general, this is a very brittle approach to scripting git – there is no guarantee that the output of `git status` doesn't change between git versions. A better approach would be using `git status --porcelain` (see [docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-status#Documentation/git-status.txt---porcelainltversiongt)).

Comment: When I issue `git status -uno` against an up to date branch the return from `git status` has line feeds in it. Those don't seem to be accounted for in your `$text` variable.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Better do this, `=~` for *bash regex* :

```
#!/bin/bash

var="$(git status -uno)" 

if [[ $var =~ "nothing to commit" ]]; then
    echo "Up-to-date"
else
    echo "need to pull"
fi
```

or

```
#!/bin/bash

var="$(git status -uno)" 

if [[ $var == *nothing\ to\ commit* ]]; then
    echo "Up-to-date"
else
    echo "need to pull"
fi
```

Comment: [tag:bash] *regex* is performance killer!

Comment: New script is quicker

Comment: What does =~ mean?

Answer (score 4):

**Warning:** [bash](/questions/tagged/bash)'s regex require more ressources and won't work in other [shell](/questions/tagged/shell)!

## Simple old fashion

This syntax is *POSIX* compatible, not [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) only!

```
if LANG=C git status -uno | grep -q up-to-date ; then
    echo "Nothing to do"
else
    echo "Need to upgrade"
fi
```

## Or testing a variable ([posix](/questions/tagged/posix) too)

From [this answer to ***How to check if a string contains a substring in Bash***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20460402/1765658), here is a compatible syntax, working under **any** *standard POSIX shell*:

```
#!/bin/sh

stringContain() { [ -z "${2##*$1*}" ] && { [ -z "$1" ] || [ -n "$2" ] ;} ; }

var=$(git status -uno)

if  stringContain "up-to-date" "$var" ;then
    echo "Up-to-date"
    # Don't do anything
else
    echo "need to pull"
    # Ask for upgrade, see: 
fi
```

Comment: Closing the question as a duplicate (with the dupehammer, nonetheless) *and* answering it is a bit odd, no?

Comment: @BenjaminW. I agree, it was late, I answered spontaneously, then I realized: title of quest stand for *output of a command*, but question itsefl is about a *variable check"...