# Why is the check not working as I expect it to?

Tags: bash

Using bash 4.2, I have an associative array.

I want to check if the value at a key contains or not a string. To achieve this, based on this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/229551/how-to-check-if-a-string-contains-a-substring-in-bash),
i do the following:

```
ERRORS[TEST]="TEST"
if [[ ! ERRORS[TEST] =~ "TEST" ]]; then
    echo "failed"
else
    echo "succeed"
fi
```

This should echo failed, but it echoes succeed.

What I am missing or not understanding in this behavior ? If my method is wrong, how can I achieve this ?

Comment: To access array index use: `"${ERRORS[TEST]}"`

Comment: @anubhava: In quotes?  Maybe it doesn't matter with `[[` but it feels sloppy to an old-time programmer (and the fact that the syntax inside `[[` is different from normal is one of the reasons I really dislike `[[`).

Comment: Yes I meant only for `[[ ... ]]` though it never hurts to use quotes *always* in shell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `${ERRORS[TEST]}`. That is the way to get the value of associative array.

`ERRORS[TEST]` will just return the code as-is.

BTW, when `ERRORS[TEST]="TEST"`, the code should echo "succeed". As you have a `!` ahead of it, which means it echos "failed" when the variable does not contain "TEST". It would echo "succeed" as it actually contains one.

BTW x2, if you use `ERRORS[TEST]` instead of `${ERRORS[TEST]}`, it would also echo "succeed". But it is not correctly working as it would always return "succeed" as "TEST" is included in "ERRORS[**TEST**]", regardless of the actual value of the variable.