# Using Bitbucket's $BITBUCKET_TAG variable in an IF statement

Tags: continuous-integration, bitbucket, continuous-deployment, bitbucket-pipelines, bitbucket-cloud

I've been scratching my head all day trying to figure this out. Could somebody point me out as to why

`- if [ $BITBUCKET_BRANCH == 'master' ]; echo "Do master branch stuff"; fi`

works just fine when trying to run some code if the branch I pushed to is `master`.

But when I'm trying to distiguish it by tags with

`- if [ $BITBUCKET_TAG == 'test-*' ]; then echo "Do test tag stuff"; fi`

it is completely ignored, as if the code inside the `if` statement is never reached.

What am I doing wrong? I tried to change the statements in multiple ways, tried using regex, etc. to no avail. Any help would really be appreciated.

Here's a reproducible sample pipeline code:

```
image: node:12.16.0
options:
  docker: true

definitions:
  steps: 
    - step: &if-test
        name: If test
        script:   

          - if [ $BITBUCKET_BRANCH == 'master' ]; then echo "Do master branch stuff"; fi

          - if [ $BITBUCKET_TAG == 'test-*' ]; then echo "Do test tag stuff"; fi

          - if [ $BITBUCKET_TAG == 'staging-*' ]; then echo "Do staging tag stuff"; fi

pipelines:
  branches:
    master: 
      - step: *if-test

  tags:    

    'test-*': 
      - step: *if-test

    'staging-*': 
      - step: *if-test
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the way you have coded the `"if"` statement:

```sh
if [ $BITBUCKET_TAG == 'test-*' ];
```

This is a bash/unix `if` statement, which will check for a literal string `"test-*"` as the branch name, which you probably don't use.

You should use a **['string contains'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/229551/check-if-string-contains-substring-in-bash)** test instead of a **'string equals'** test, like this:

```sh
if [[ $BITBUCKET_TAG == *"test-"* ]];
```

Also note that the `yml` usage of `'test-*'` here...

```yaml
tags:
  'test-*':
```

... is different to how a bash/shell script interprets `'test-*'`.

Comment: Yes, I did find that post and figure it out 10 min after having written this question. The answer was right in front of me - it's just Bash after all, and instead of digging through the Atlassian docs for hours I could have just looked for Bash... And yes, I felt extremely silly... Anyway, thanks a lot!