# What is the simplest way to tell if a string is in a list of strings in bash?

Tags: arrays, bash

The FOR loop has the following syntax:

```
for v in `cat test.txt`
do
  ...
done
```

I want to know if there is a syntax like:

```
if v in  `cat test.txt`
then
   ...
fi
```

Basically, I want to know if a string is in a variable that contains a list of strings. The bash array should be able to do this. But I want a simpler solution.

Comment: Why don’t you use grep?

Comment: If you want to know if a string contains something, check this.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/229551/how-to-check-if-a-string-contains-a-substring-in-bash

Comment: Yes, I can use grep or string match, but that seems a little odd. I need to tell if an element is in a list, not match a string against a line or the whole variable.

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: How did you define your variable? The best way to do this is to make it an associative array, with the strings you want to search for as keys.