# Bash substring comparison doesn't work for command expression

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I am trying to compare a substring in bash ([How to check if a string contains a substring in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/229551/how-to-check-if-a-string-contains-a-substring-in-bash)). Normally I can do this like so:

```
if [[ "sdfdsfOpenSSHdsfsdf" == *"OpenSSH"* ]]; then echo "substring found"; fi
```

However, when using an interactive command it doesn't work:

```
if [[ $(ssh -V) == *"OpenSSH"* ]]; then echo "substring found"; fi
```

The output of `ssh -V` is `OpenSSH_8.4p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1h  22 Sep 2020`, so I would expect the substring to be matched. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the output of `ssh -V` goes to stderr, you need to redirect to `stdout` in order to capture it:

```
ssh -V 2>&1
```

so the following works:

```
if [[ $(ssh -V 2>&1) == *"OpenSSH"* ]]; then echo "substring found"; fi
```

Comment: Ah, that makes perfect sense. Didn't know that the version output goes to stderr. Thanks!