# Expect - how to find out if variable contains a string

Tags: string, variables, conditional-statements, expect

Hello Stack over flowers ;-)

I am looking for equivalent of bash's command, but for expect:

```
VAR="ble something"

if [[ "$VAR" =~ "*something" ]]; then
  VAR2="XYZ"
else
  VAR2="YYY"
fi
echo $VAR2

# VAR2 = YYY in that case
```

I tried something like

```
if {[$VAR =~ "*3*"]}
{
set VAR2 "XYZ"
puts "$VAR2"
}
else
{
set VAR2 "YYY"
puts "$VAR2"
}
```

...but no luck. Thank you in advance for Your help.

Comment: Please take a look at this thread:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/229551/how-to-check-if-a-string-contains-a-substring-in-bash

Comment: [tag:expect] uses [tag:tcl] which is a different language. you can try my [sexpect](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect) if you are more comfortable with shell commands.

Comment: to learn Tcl you can refer to its official doc: https://www.tcl.tk/doc/

Answer (score 0):

Expect is really an extension to the Tcl language, which means you can use `string match`:

```
if {[string match "*3*" $VAR]} {
    # It is a match, do something
} else {
    # Not a match
}
```

The `string match` command returns 1 if it matches, and 0 if it does not. Note that `string match` behaves like wildcard match, not regular expression match.