# How to extract tag name from `git describe --all` regardless of whether it is annotated or lightweight

Tags: bash, git

Just a quick question:

`git describe` returns `v0.1.0`.

`git describe --all` returns `tags/v0.1.0`.

I need to extract v0.1.0 regardless of whether it has a `tags/` prefix. How do I do this?

```
# This should echo "false"
if [ $(git describe --all) = "v0.1.0" ]
then
  echo "true"
else
  echo "false"
fi
```

Comment: Maybe have a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/229551/how-to-check-if-a-string-contains-a-substring-in-bash

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! `if [ *$(git describe --all --exact-match)* = $(git log -n 1 --pretty=format:%s $hash) ]` tells me `zsh: no matches found: *tags/TEST*`

Answer (score 0):

The `--all` option means *consider all tags **and** all branches **and** all other refs*.  As such, it always produces `tags/string` or `heads/name` or, e.g., `remotes/origin/next` (or fails; see below).

- If you expect the result to always be a tag, just check that it starts with `tags/`.
- If you want to *force* the result to always be a tag, even if that's a lightweight tag, but never a *branch* name, use `--tags` instead of `--all`.

Note, however, that `--tags` can fail, if no tag works as a descriptive entity.  This is even true for `--all`, even if there are tags.  For instance, an orphan commit created on a detached HEAD when there are no branch names will do the trick:

```
$ mkdir ttag
$ cd ttag
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in ...
$ echo test > README
$ git add README
$ git commit -m initial
[master (root-commit) 7e9de28] initial
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 README
$ git checkout --detach
HEAD is now at 7e9de28 initial
$ git branch -d master
Deleted branch master (was 7e9de28).
$ git describe --all
fatal: No names found, cannot describe anything.
```

Here's a different example to show how `--all` can fail even if there are tags:

```
$ cd .../git
$ git describe
v2.33.1-835-ge9e5ba39a7
$ git checkout --orphan dummy
Switched to a new branch 'dummy'
$ git commit -m for-describe-error
[dummy (root-commit) 06145997e1] for-describe-error
 3989 files changed, 1384670 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 .cirrus.yml
 create mode 100644 .clang-format
 create mode 100644 .editorconfig
[tons of output snipped]
$ git describe --all
heads/dummy
HEAD is now at 06145997e1 for-describe-error
$ git describe --all
heads/dummy
$ git describe --all
fatal: No tags can describe '06145997e15516ce13b24d94ca70ecb7cec8863f'.
Try --always, or create some tags.
$ git checkout master
Warning: you are leaving 1 commit behind, not connected to
[snip warning I didn't really need since that was the idea]
```

To force `git describe` not to fail, use `--always`:

```
$ git describe --always
7e9de28
```

It's not really clear to me what your purpose in using `--all` here was, but if you just want to know if the *current commit* has *some tag*, whether the tag is lightweight or annotated, use `git describe --tags --exact-match`.  This either:

- fails, because no tag matches; or
- succeeds and prints the tag name of the matching tag.

By redirecting stderr away and checking the status, you can tell if there was a tag:

```
if tag=$(git describe --tags --exact-match 2>/dev/null); then
    ... this commit is tagged ...
else
    ... this commit is not tagged ...
fi
```

and that seems to fit the text of your question, but makes me wonder why you were using `--all` in the first place.

Note: to check whether a variable `$v` holds something that starts with the given prefix, the `case` statement is actually the short and sweet method:

```
case "$v" in
foo*) echo "prefixed with foo";;
bar*) echo "prefixed with bar";;
*) echo "not prefixed with foo or bar";;
esac
```

This works for a variable that might hold `tags/*` or `heads/*`.