# How to check if a string is equal to another string based in a substring in Bash

Tags: bash

I'm trying to do the following:

I have this file called testing.txt that I want to update each time the ip address or addresses change based on the name (test1ip, test2ip):

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
somotherrandomip testing
192.168.0.36 test1ip
192.168.0.37 test2ip
```

This is what I've tried.

```
#!/bin/bash
array=(
        "192.168.0.34 test1ip"
        "192.168.0.35 test2ip"
)

for i in "${array[@]}"; do
        if ! grep -Fxq "$i" testing.txt
        then
                echo "ip-name=$i is not present, so adding it in testing.txt file" 
                echo "$i" >> testing.txt
        else
                echo "ip-name=$i is present in file, so nothing to do"
        fi
done
```

However, this script appends a completely new line if the line is not found. What I would like to achieve is to overwrite the line if test1ip or test2ip is found but the ip address change.

Expected result:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
somotherrandomip testing
192.168.0.34 test1ip
192.168.0.35 test2ip
```

I've also read this [How to check if a string contains a substring in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/229551/how-to-check-if-a-string-contains-a-substring-in-bash/229585#229585) but it seems i can't figure it out.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following works on my machine. I changed the array to an associative array, removed the -x option to grep, and used `sed` to edit the file in place.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

#associative array
declare -A array=(
        [test1ip]="192.168.0.34"
        [test2ip]="192.168.0.35"
)

#Loop over keys of the array
#See parameter expansion in bash manpage
for i in "${!array[@]}"; do
        if ! grep -Fq "$i" testing.txt
        then
                echo "ip-name=$i is not present, so adding it in testing.txt file" 
                echo "${array[$i]} $i" >> testing.txt
        else
                echo "ip-name=$i is present in file so running sed"

                #Escape sed left hand side
                #Adapted for extended regular expressions from https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/129063/309759
                i=$(printf '%s\n' "$i" | sed 's:[][\\/.^$*+?(){}|]:\\&:g')

                #Excape right hand side
                ipaddr=$(printf '%s\n' "${array[$i]}" | sed 's:[\\/&]:\\&:g;$!s/$/\\/')

                #Replace old IP vith new IP
                sed -Ei "s/[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+){3} +$i/$ipaddr $i/" testing.txt
        fi
done
```

Comment: Thanks @Nathan for helping out on this.

Comment: You might need to escape the hostnames for using them in `sed` as string literals; for example `example.test` will match `examplestest`. Also, while you correctly fixed @chiko code, you didn't pointed out that using `grep` and `sed` inside the `for` loop shall be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a `bash` + `awk` solution that'll do the job efficiently:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

array=(
    "192.168.0.34 test1ip"
    "192.168.0.35 test2ip"
    "192.168.0.33 test3ip"
)

awk '
    FNR == NR {
        aarr[$2] = $1
        next
    }
    ! ($2 in aarr)
    END {
        for (host in aarr)
            print aarr[host], host
    }
' <(printf '%s\n' "${array[@]}") testing.txt
```

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
somotherrandomip testing
192.168.0.33 test3ip
192.168.0.34 test1ip
192.168.0.35 test2ip
```

**notes:**

- `bash`'s `<( commands )` is called *process-subtitution*. It creates a file containing the output of `commands` that you can use as argument.
- `awk`'s `FNR == NR` is a condition for selecting the first file argument. In this block I create an associative array that translates a hostname to its new IP address.
- `! ($2 in aarr)` means to print the records for which the hostname is **not** in the translation array.
- The `END` is for printing the translation array (new IPs of hostnames).

Comment: Thanks @Fravadona for your help and time.