# Makefile. How do I find substring for given string and use it with if condition

Tags: makefile

I'm trying to check if given string contains another. It should go like:

Case 1: `"abc" in "abc" # True`

Case 2: `"ab" in "abc" # True`

Case 3: `"x" in "abc"  # False`

```
if test $(findstring "ab", "abc"); then \
    echo "YES"; \
else \
    echo "NO "; \
fi;

# NO
```

It seems that `findstring` is matching words only but not searching substrings (it is not correct for Case 2). Is there another simple way to do it?

Comment: Note make doesn't treat quotes as special in any way.  It's just another character as far as make as concerned, like `x` or `q`.  So your call is not right: you would want to run `$(findstring ab,abc)`, without quotes.  That would expand to the empty string if it wasn't found, or else the matched string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing `make` syntax and shell syntax. Generally, you want to use shell syntax in recipes.

```
target: prerequisites
    case "abc" in *"ab"*) echo yes;; *) echo no;; esac
```

For further variations, see also [How to check if a string contains a substring in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/229551/how-to-check-if-a-string-contains-a-substring-in-bash)

The `[` aka `test` command is somewhat brittle. If you know your shell is actually Bash, you can use `[[`; but then you separately have to tell `make` that (`SHELL := /bin/bash`) and this obviously makes your code less portable.

```
othertarget: other prereqs
    if [[ "abc" = *"ab"* ]]; then echo yes; else echo no; fi
    # if the commands are simple, a convenient shorthand:
    [[ "abc" = *"ab"* ]] && echo yes || echo no
```

Your problem with `findstring` is that `"ab"` really isn't a substring of `"abc"` (it would be a substring of `"ab"c`).

Comment: somehow first and second solution shows me "no" in all cases. Third one works fine but also empty string *""* is considered as True/match?

Comment: Sorry, my bad, the `*"substring"*` syntax only works with `[[`. Answer updated. I can't repro the empty string case; `case "" in *"ab"*) echo yes;; *) echo no;; esac` prints `no` for me.

Comment: Thanks for correction. The case is: `case "abc" in *""*) echo yes;; *) echo no;; esac` gives yes, I would expect no. First string is "searched string" and second "substring", so when substring is empty then it shows "yes".

Comment: Every string has the empty string as a substring. What other result could you possibly expect? After quote removal the pattern simply becomes `**` which is every possible string (twice!)