# How to search for a substring including wildcard passed through a variable in Bash?

Tags: string, bash, shell, substring, sh

Bash allows [checking for a substring](https://stackoverflow.com/a/229606/318765).

It is even possible to use the wildcard symbol `*` inside the search string:

```
# works
line="foo bar baz"
if [[ $line == *"foo "*" baz"* ]]; then
  echo "found"
fi
```

1.) But how do I pass the search string including the wildcard through a variable?

```
# fails
line="foo bar baz"
search='foo "*" baz'
echo "$search"
if [[ $line == *"$search"* ]]; then
  echo "found"
fi
```

2.) And if it is possible through escaping: How do I manipulate `$search`, so the user of my script can simply pass `foo * baz`?

The only solution I found is this, but it is limited to a specific maximum amount of wildcards and it does not feel like the best way to solve this:

```
line="foo bar baz"
search="foo * baz"
IFS=\* read -r search1 search2 search3 search4 <<< "$search"
if [[ $line == *"$search1"*"$search2"*"$search3"*"$search4"* ]]; then
  echo "found"
fi
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually simple: don't quote the variable containing the search pattern, or include quotes in the search variable (unless you want to search for literal quotes).

```
line="foo bar baz"
search="foo * baz"
if [[ $line == *$search* ]]; then
  echo "found"
fi
```

Explanation: if parts of the pattern (i.e. the thing on the right side of the `=` or `==` operator in `[[ ]]`) are quoted, they're treated as literal rather than as glob patterns. Thus, putting double-quotes around `$search` makes bash treat the `*` in its value as just a literal character rather than a wildcard. Removing the double-quotes makes bash treat it as a wildcard.

Note that this doesn't apply to quotes in the variable's value; those will be treated as literal whether or not the variable is quoted. So if you use `search='foo "*" baz'`, it's going to be looking for double-quotes in the line whether or not you double-quote `$search`.

Comment: Ah nice. Finally I needed to escape the other wildcard characters like `search=${search//[/\\[}; search=${search//]/\\]}; search=${search//\?/\\?}` as they should be searchable as a literal string. Any other characters, which I need to escape?

Comment: If there are any literal backslashes, you need to escape them as well (and do it before the other characters, or you'll be escaping *those* escapes...). If you have `extglob` (extended glob syntax) enabled, things are more complex and I'm not sure exactly what needs escaping.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you can use `case`:

```
$ search="foo * baz"; case "foo bar baz" in $search) echo found ;; esac
found
```